# How to change a view in a nib file on change of drop down value which is in same nib file in a bundle project?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, bundle, swift5

I am working on a bundle project for MacOS and I am new to Swift and MacOS development. How can I change view of a nib file on change of value in drop down(Which is also in same nib file)?

[image: Example:]

As you see a drop down and it has a value item 1, when I select item one in drop down the below view should show a specific view in the example it is item 1 view and if I select another value in drop down lets just say item 2 I should be able to dynamically(Programatically) change the item 1 view to item 2 view. So, how can I achieve this in swift bundle project? **I can't use story boards.**

Comment: Can get your project github url should be very easy to handle

Comment: Use a tabless tab view and switch tab.

Comment: I need to do change sub view on drop down value change @Willeke

Answer (score 3):

Create your views programatically or instantiate then from Nib or StoryBoard files, then add them as subviews.
Have a look on [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit).

But your question should probably be: Teach me UI coding using Apple Frameworks.
StackOverflow is the wrong place for that.